# Android XML shows different than live version

Tags: android

I can not figure out what is going on. For awhile everything was perfect, I have the style sheet setup for the application and in the manifest I have each individual activity set to that theme. It was working for awhile but now it is changing all the items that show white to black and I cannot figure out why.Here's a picture of the way it is supposed to have worked and was working for awhile

[image: How it should be (Shows on android designer)]

How it shows in emulator and on phones

[image]

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/signinbg">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:text="login"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:background="@color/Blueish"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:password="true"
        android:singleLine="true"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Not registered yet? Sign up!"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/Register"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Username"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Password"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:id="@+id/ForgotPassword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Styles:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: please post layout file and styles.xml

Comment: @NaN I wen't ahead and added the styles sheet.

Comment: everything seems fine to me, maybe you changed @color/white accidently, would you check it?

Comment: @NaN @color/white is indeed #ffffff

Comment: The theme has  nothing to do with TextView textColor and as you mentioned the white is set correctly, Didn't you change textColor in code?

Comment: Your phone and emulator are showing an older holo-based theme. What version of Android do you have on your phone or emulator?